# Formatting nullable decimal in RazorEngine

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

RazorEngine.dll version is 3.2.

Example code inside a razor engine template (cshtml file) :

```
      @foreach(var row in Model.Trades)
      {            
          <tr>          
             <td>
                @string.Format("{0:N2}",row.Amount)
             </td>
          </tr>
      }
```

where row.Amount is defined in the Trades class as :
public decimal? Amount;

The stack trace fromRazorEngine is :

```
> System.ArgumentNullException was caught   HResult=-2147467261  
> Message=Value cannot be null. Parameter name: args   Source=mscorlib  
> ParamName=args   StackTrace:
>        at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
>        at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite
> site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
>        at CompiledRazorTemplates.Dynamic.ccdceaafafffaefee.Execute()
>        at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase.RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplate.Run(ExecuteContext
> context) in
> c:\Users\Matthew\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateBase.cs:line
> 126
>        at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Run(ITemplate template, DynamicViewBag viewBag) in
> c:\Users\Matthew\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line
> 608
>        at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse(String razorTemplate, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag, String cacheName)
> in
> c:\Users\Matthew\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line
> 439
>        at RazorEngine.Razor.Parse[T](String razorTemplate, T model, String cacheName) in
> c:\Users\Matthew\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Razor.cs:line
> 276
```

The error occurs when Amount is null. 
This is a workaround which seems to work ok :

```
@foreach(var row in Model.Trades)
{            
   <tr>          
      <td>
         @if (row.Amount != null)
         {                
           <text>@string.Format("{0:N4}", row.Amount)</text>
         }
     </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Any ideas, or at least a better workaround ?
Thanks.

EDIT :

The workaround below is a bit more compact :

```
         <td>
            @(row.Amount == null ? "" : row.Amount.ToString("N4"))
         </td>
```

Does anyone know if Razor in MVC behaves in the same way ? Or is this behaviour specific to RazorEngine.dll ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error above is from String.Format(). Interesting, as the documentation on [String.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format.aspx) explains that null arguments should result in empty string.

For whatever reason Razor selects the overload [String.Format(format, Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) to format your string. As your value is `null`.

I've created a [small example](https://gist.github.com/steven-r/eba9fda6d6e4b2c9e0ac) at to explain the problem:

```
int? val = null;

// this one fails:
string template = "Hello @string.Format(\"{0:N4}\", Model.Value)! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Value = val });

// this (ugly) workaround works:
string template = "Hello @(string.Format(\"{0:N4}{1}\", Model.Value, string.Empty))! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Value = val });

// this (not so ugly) workaround works as well:
string template = "Hello @(string.Format(\"{0:N4}\", (Object)Model.Value))! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Value = val });
```

Your workaround will work as well.

If this is a bug or a feature in Razor, I do not know...

**EDIT (2)**: Added the smarter workaround from [Moe Sisko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70140/moe-sisko)

**EDIT**: Rewrote to really answer the question ...

Comment: thanks, but I don't want anything to be displayed when Amount is null. (Or displaying an empty string when Amount is null would be ok).

Comment: Hello, I rewrote the answer to come back to your question, sorry.

Comment: thanks, the example is great. Another workaround which seems to work is  @string.Format("{0:N2}", (object) row.Amount)

Comment: I think the reason is that you use anonymous types, which means RazorEngine has to use the type `dynamic`. So it's a feature not a bug :). This explains the workaround as well.