# null dynamic variable and function overloading

Tags: c#, .net

Example code :

```
private void DoSomething(object obj)
{
    MessageBox.Show("called object");
}

private void DoSomething(params object[] obj)
{
    MessageBox.Show("called object[]");
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal? amount = null;
    dynamic obj = amount;

    DoSomething(obj); 
}
```

When button 1 is clicked, the message "called object[]" is displayed. It seems that the overloaded method with object[] parameter is preferred in this example. Any ideas why ? I'm just curious more than anything.

(Background : this behavior caused some unexpected results in Razor with dynamic views
[Formatting nullable decimal in RazorEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868008/formatting-nullable-decimal-in-razorengine)).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's because you can cast `object[]` to `object` and not the other way around. `object[]` is more specific and therefore favored in method resolution.

> **7.5.3.2 Better function member**
>
> (...)
>
> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions `{ E1, E2, ..., EN }` and two applicable function members `MP` and `MQ` with parameter types `{ P1, P2, ..., PN }` and `{ Q1, Q2, ..., QN }`, `MP` is defined to be a better function member than `MQ` if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from `EX` to `QX` is not better than the implicit conversion from `EX` to `PX`, and
> - for at least one argument, the conversion from `EX` to `PX` is better than the conversion from `EX` to `QX`.

And later on the *better conversion target* gets defined:

> **7.5.3.5 Better conversion target**
>
> Given two different types `T1` and `T2`, `T1` is a better conversion target than `T2` if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - An implicit conversion from `T1` to `T2` exists, and no implicit conversion from `T2` to `T1` exists
>
> (...)

In your example `T1` is `object[]` and `T2` is `object`.

Comment: for anyone wondering, the book being quoted in this answer is: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=s-IH_x6ytuQC

Comment: @imlokesh You're wrong. I was quoting C# specification, not a book.

Comment: my bad, I searched for the exact text you quoted and this was the first result. :)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not specific to "null dynamic variable". Even if you call `DoSomething(null)`, the `object[]` overload will be preferred.

This is because even though null can be either `object` or `object[]`, the latter is preferred due to it being a *Better Conversion Target* as explained by [MarcinJuraszek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30092948/1311748).

However, if you specify the type explicitly like this:

```
object x = null;
DoSomething(x);
```

Then the `object` overload will be called since the compiler already knows the type of the null variable.